# flask-wtf как сохранить значение в поле после его оправки

Tags: flask

Подскажите пожалуйста, как во flask-wtf после отправки значения формы сделать так, чтобы введенное значение поля сохранялось в этом поле?

Answer (score 2):

Значения полей можно установить при создании экземпляра формы с помощью передачи параметров в конструктор

```
form = UserForm(first_name='John', last_name='Doe')
```

или передачей объекта с одноимёнными полями вторым параметром

```
some_user = User(first_name='John', last_name='Doe')
form = UserForm(request.form, some_user)
```